# Python Regular expressions for alpha numeric digits

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions and trying to do the following:

Below is the format of a series of alpha numeric digits. It starts with 4 digits followed by 2 spaces followed by 8 digits followed by a single space followed by 8 digits followed by a single space followed by 8 digits followed by a single space followed by 8 digits followed by a single space followed by an OR bar.

```
FFFF  FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF |
```

or written more clearly:

```
FFFF[space][space]FFFFFFFF[space]FFFFFFFF[space]FFFFFFFF[space]FFFFFFFF[space]|
```

I first need to find the correct line in a file which starts with 00A3. Then I need to pull out the digit groups which I have framed with the using:

```
p = re.compile('00A3  ') # search for 00A3[space][space]
r = re.compile(???)      # search for desired 8 digit groups
q = re.compile(\[SECTION2\])

dataString = inFile.next() # 00A3 388A63FF 00000DF1 52984731 FF989ACB
while not q.match(dataString) # look for [SECTION2] line in file. This means we passed where 00A3 would have been so it must not be here.
    if p.match(dataString):
        numbers = r.findall(dataString) # numbers = [388A63FF, 00000DF1, 52984731, FF989ACB]
        break
    dataString = inFile.next() # get next line to check
```

This should give me a list of the numbers for further processing. Im just not sure how to write the regex that will find only the 4 groups of 8 alpha numeric digits seperated with a space. My thought was to look for 8 alpha numeric digits together with a space in front and a space behind, but would that cause a problem and how would that look?

I looked into the look ahead and look behind options, but i get confused.

I am still very new to this, especially in Python so I am open to suggestions on better implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one regular expression for a single 8 digit group and then find all the matches in a line.

```
line = #string

regex = re.compile(r' (\w{8})')

groups = regex.findall(line) #gives a list of the matches in order of appearance
```

Comment: This worked great. I had some issues with the other suggestions. Thanks for the help with regex's!

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\d{4}\s{2})(\d{8}\s){4}(?=[\s|])
```

Comment: You may want to use `[^\W_]` instead of `\d`

Comment: Although I suspect he'll want to change the `\d{4}` to `00A3` or whatever literal string he needs, and use `[\dA-F]` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using findall, you should be ok with

`\w{8}`

It matches all the the hex numbers that are 8 digits long.

Answer (score 0):

re: differing implementations

```
all_numbers =[]
with open('input','r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.split()
        if line[0] == "00A3":
            numbers = line[1:5]
            all_numbers.append(numbers)
```

`numbers` looks like `['388A63FF', '00000DF1', '52984731', 'FF989ACB']` and `all_numbers` is just a list of the numbers found.